# catch exceptions from yodlee api

Tags: php, yodlee

Currently I'm working with the yodlee API. As specified in the [documentation](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/coblogin) the url response may throw `InvalidCredentails` or `UserAccountLocked`. I'm using PHP and I get the following response when the username or password is incorrect.

```
{
  Error: [ 
     {
       errorDetail: "Invalid Cobrand Credentials"
     }
  ]
}
```

So to check if the error occurs I want to write some code that checks if `errorDetail` has a value of `Invalid Cobrand Credentials`.
So far ok.

But the there may be so many types of errors, and each error name is different. My question is: Can I get the list of these `errorDetail` values
so that I can make it work without checking if the code is forcebly throwing the errors.

Comment: You'd have to consult the API documentation further if you want a list of available error messages (that would be off-topic). Good guess that there's no fixed list however when they're just sending readable text. So use a standard Exception and `errorDetail` as its message.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for the `Error` index and access it's value for throwing the errors. Something like this should work for you (not tested). From the repo page:

```
yodleeAPI.getAccounts(accessToken)
  .then(function(response) {})
  .catch(function(error) {});
```

Edit:
As far as I could tell there wasn't any exception list. So you're either going to have to go through all the exceptions manually or create a generic error message for users. I would just advice to catch the exception message and use that for the user view(if there isn't any security information in there). You can accomplish that by following the above code.
If you do feel the need to go through every exception yourself I managed to at least get the list of all methods that throw exceptions (search: exception). You'll have to go through it yourself, and parse the error message yourself. But you can find that [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Special:Search?search=exception&qid=51282&page=5&as=True)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Bono , as you said i will throw an exception saying with message as returned by the yodlee api, to catch that exception also i want to write code some where there i want to check the message with string like `Invalid Cobrand Credentials` so that i can render the view for user so and so by analysing the exception message, any where i want to write the code for different type of exception. actually my questionis there any  list of exception strings like `Invalid Cobrand Exception`.

Comment: @PavanKumar I've updated the answer. Unfortunately I don't think there is a list you're looking for.